# Copy file paths using .bat file into a txt file

Tags: file, batch-file, dos

How can I use a .bat file to copy only the file paths from a directory?

For example, I have a folder with 1000 files in it. I need a full UNC path for each file put into a text file. This would include the file extension well.

Comment: Try `dir /s /b directory > file.txt`

Comment: Actually /s flag gives all the subdirectories as well.

Comment: And /b (or any other switch) won't give the full path.

Comment: @Bond when I used `/s` with `/b` I get full path names. 
user3338797, you didn't stipulate that you didn't want to traverse subdirectories, so I wasn't aware.

Comment: @mbratch: The OP mentioned he has a folder with 1000 files in it, so it sounded like he wanted to get the full path names of just those 1000 files. Your solution would only work if there were no subdirectories. Otherwise, it's going to give him (potentially much) more than he wants.

Comment: @Bond yes, I know that now. :) That requirement wasn't obvious to me. If someone says to me, "I have a folder with 1,000 files in it" I believe they could potentially mean including subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

Copy only the file paths:

```
(for %a in (*.*) do @echo %~DPa) > output.txt
```

Copy file paths with extensions:

```
(for %a in (*.*) do @echo %~DPXa) > output.txt
```

Previous are command-lines; you may include they in a Batch file, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It's always surprised me that the DIR command doesn't have an option to display the full path of the files. Anyway, here's a VBScript solution:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Out = .CreateTextFile("c:\text.txt", True)
    For Each File In .GetFolder("c:\some_folder").Files
        Out.WriteLine File.Path
    Next
    Out.Close
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Get full paths using the `~f` modifier

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /a-d/b') do @echo %~fA >> list.txt
```

**Note:** Remember to double those percents if using inside a batch file.